# Marketing a browser game with a specific audience

Tags: graphics, browser-based-games, game-industry, marketing, trailer

My issue is that I have extensively developed an online browser game, but mainly the marketing and independent developer guides tailor to action packed executable games. My game also tailors to a specific audience that is not typically on the indie gaming promotional websites. Namely those interested in Politics, Economy, Law, and/or Sociology.

(My first issue) I wanted to know if there are any suggestions, ideas, or references to any resources that may bring marketing value to my gaming community pre and post-launch? I have began development on my beta campaign already to include some crowd funding websites (mostly for promotion), a press kit, advertisements, and the like. However I would greatly appreciate more resources for the development and launch, namely for the target audience.

(My second issue) Many of the marketing strategies for games depend on a video, game photos, etc. While I can take photos of the screen, there are not too many things I can do for a video except add some stock footage and dress it up by explaining game mechanics and showing some photos of the game. Would that contribute to the game or is it just a waste of time? (Feel free to suggest any ideas for this as well if you are willing).

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 2):

You have a very specific audience? That's great, because it means that your advertisement is easy to target.

- Go to where your target demographic is. Find out what communication channels they use, and pitch your game there. But tread lightly: Communities are allergic to people who are obviously only there to promote a product, so make sure your participation is constructive and in accordance with the written and unwritten rules of the community. A good method is to not ask them to buy, but rather ask them for feedback how well your game captures their area of interest and advice how to make it better. Your first goal should not be to get people to want your product, but just to talk about your product. When people talk about it, those who want it will appear on their own.
- Contact any news media commonly consumed by your target demographic, even when not game-specific. When your game is very unique and relevant for the demographic, its existence alone might make it newsworthy, even for media which usually does not report about games. Contacting smaller blogs and websites likely has a better chance of success, but you have nothing to lose by also writing to the big names.
- When you are willing to invest some money into advertisement, most web advertisement services allow you to pick the interests of the people you want to see your ads.

Comment: I have been thinking about something similar to this, but you really put it all together and made it much more clear for me. Thank you so much!

Comment: @StaceyB When I was able to answer your question, please mark it as "accepted answer" by clicking on the tick-icon next to it.